# Link function in an __init__

Tags: python, object, init

I am doing some coding in python and I've come across little problem : 
I defined several version of functions and want to assign one of them in the `__init__` function when I create my object. I need those function to have a `self` argument.

I found a way to do it but I cannot tell if I am using the language correctly.

In my_class.py

```
class my_class(object):
    fun_1 = lambda self,val: self.attr + val
    fun_2 = lambda self,val: self.attr - val


    def __init__(self, attr, fun_version):
        self.attr = attr

        my_class.fun = my_class.__dict__['fun_' + str(fun_version)]
```

In test.py

```
import my_class

my_instance_1 = my_class.my_class(attr = 2, fun_version = 1)
print(my_instance_1.fun(1))

my_instance_2 = my_class.my_class(attr = 2, fun_version = 2)
print(my_instance_2.fun(1))
```

The result follows what is expected :

```
3
1
```

Is there more elegant way to do it ? I find awkward to define a class method in the `__init__` function.

Comment: You are aware that if two objects with different `fun_version` are created, the last construction defines the method to use for the whole class (affecting all objects, also earlier created ones)?

Comment: No I didn’t ! And that’s a behavior I want to avoid. Is there a way to create a fun that is linked with one instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve what you want is (class and test code in one file for simplicity):

```
class my_class(object):
    fun_1 = lambda self,val: self.attr + val
    fun_2 = lambda self,val: self.attr - val


    def __init__(self, attr, fun_version):
        self.attr = attr

        self.fun = getattr(self, 'fun_' + str(fun_version))




my_instance_1 = my_class(attr = 2, fun_version = 1)
print(my_instance_1.fun(1))

my_instance_2 = my_class(attr = 2, fun_version = 2)
print(my_instance_2.fun(1))

#Proof that instances are independent:
print(my_instance_1.fun(1))
```

Prints:

```
3
1
3
```

If the variants of `fun` don't need instance attributes (are static methods) this can be written this way (it could also be written with `lambda` in some way similar to first variant but this will look ugly):

```
class my_class(object):
    @staticmethod
    def fun_1(val):
        return 1 + val

    @staticmethod
    def fun_2(val):
        return 2 + val


    def __init__(self, attr, fun_version):
        self.attr = attr

        self.fun = getattr(my_class, 'fun_' + str(fun_version))
        # or (as above):
        # self.fun = getattr(self, 'fun_' + str(fun_version))



my_instance_1 = my_class(attr = 2, fun_version = 1)
print(my_instance_1.fun(1))

my_instance_2 = my_class(attr = 2, fun_version = 2)
print(my_instance_2.fun(1))

print(my_instance_1.fun(1))
```

Prints

```
2
3
2
```

Comment: That’s it ! It works flawlessly. And what if for example for example ˋfunˋ  do not interact with any attribute (sum or difference of two inputs), I will still need to pass a ˋselfˋ parameter in order for it to work right ? And it is also the optimal way of doing it ?

Comment: @user185674 I updated the answer. This is the usual way if you want to provide such instance specific functions.